# Compute average for three periods of times

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following three queries which get the average price for a product for three specific period of times: all data, last 7 days and last 30 days.

```
SELECT AVG(Price) AS AggregatedPrice, COUNT(*) AS PCount
FROM dbo.Products
WHERE Id = @id

SELECT AVG(Price) AS AggregatedPrice, COUNT(*) AS PCount
FROM dbo.Products
WHERE Id = @id AND DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 7

SELECT AVG(Price) AS AggregatedPrice, COUNT(*) AS PCount
FROM dbo.Products
WHERE Id = @id AND DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 30
```

Those three queries give me the right data, but not in the form I want. Is there a way to combine those three queries into one. My final goal is to create a view with all this data on one row.

In addition, it appears to me that the average computed for the 7 days could be reused for the 30 days and all the list. Is there an optimization that I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. Make sure to test properly

```
SELECT
      AVG(Price) AS AggregatedPrice
    , COUNT(*) AS PCount
    , AVG(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 7 THEN Price ELSE Null End) AS AggregatedPrice7Days
    , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 End) AS AggregatedPrice7Days
    , AVG(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 30 THEN Price ELSE Null End) AS AggregatedPrice30Days
    , SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 End) AS AggregatedPrice30Days
FROM
    dbo.Products
WHERE
    Id = @id
```

Comment: Awesome! I looked at the execution plan for this one and it's definitely faster than having 3 selects.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @Id
       , t1.AggregatedPrice AggregatedPrice_ALL, t1.PCount PCount_ALL
       , t2.AggregatedPrice AggregatedPrice_7, t2.PCount PCount_7
       , t3.AggregatedPrice AggregatedPrice_30, t3.PCount PCount_30
FROM
  (SELECT Id, AVG(Price) AS AggregatedPrice, COUNT(*) AS PCount
     FROM dbo.Products
    WHERE Id = @id) t1
  JOIN 
  (SELECT Id, AVG(Price) AS AggregatedPrice, COUNT(*) AS PCount
     FROM dbo.ApplicationPrice
    WHERE Id = @id AND DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 7) t2 
  ON t1.Id = t2.id
  JOIN
  (SELECT Id, AVG(Price) AS AggregatedPrice, COUNT(*) AS PCount
     FROM dbo.ApplicationPrice
    WHERE Id = @id AND DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 30) t3
  ON t1.Id = t3.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have T-SQL handy to test the syntax, but it should be something like this:

```
SELECT t1.AggregatedPrice, t1.PCount, t2.AggregatedPrice, t2.PCount, t3.AggregatedPrice, t3.PCount 
FROM
  (SELECT AVG(Price) AS AggregatedPrice, COUNT(*) AS PCount  FROM dbo.Products  WHERE Id = @id) t1,
  (SELECT AVG(Price) AS AggregatedPrice, COUNT(*) AS PCount  FROM dbo.Products  WHERE Id = @id AND DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 7) t2,
  (SELECT AVG(Price) AS AggregatedPrice, COUNT(*) AS PCount  FROM dbo.Products  WHERE Id = @id AND DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 30) t3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  AVG(Price) AS AggregatedPrice, 
        COUNT(*) AS PCount,
        AVG(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 7 THEN Price ELSE NULL END) AS AggregatedWeekPrice, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS PWeekCount,
        AVG(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 30 THEN Price ELSE NULL END) AS AggregatedMonthPrice, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, UpdatedDatetime, getdate()) < 30 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS PMonthCount,
FROM dbo.Products
WHERE Id = @id
```